# Is it specified what happens when the stack pointer is pushed on x64?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, callstack, instructions

I am programming in assembly on x64, and I intend on pushing an address within the stack. I intend on writing `push %rsp`, however, as this instruction changes the value of `%rsp`, I am not sure what value will be pushed.

Specifically if I run the following:

```
movq $0x10, %rsp
pushq %rsp
```

Will the memory address `0x8` contain `0x10` or `0x8`? Is this processor dependent or is it standard across all x64 processors?

Comment: [Instruction reference covers these cases](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push).

Comment: How is this code sequence useful to you?  If you share maybe we could comment on the larger problem you're addressing.

Comment: @ErikEidt: It can possibly be useful to `push %rsp` as part of shellcode, if RSP is currently pointing to ASCII bytes or something else you just pushed.  Or even as part of implementing `volatile int x = 10, *px = &x;` at the top of a function.  But not with `mov $0x10, %rsp` first!  So that part of example is totally artificial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Raymond Chen mentioned in the comments, it is specified in Intel's manual, HTML extract here: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push.

The value pushed is the value of `%rsp` **before** the `push` instruction.

Same for `push mem` with an addressing mode involving RSP, like `push 16(%rsp)` to copy something already on the stack.

Comment: It might help to remember that this is the "useful" one of the two possibilities, since you can `push foo` and `push rsp` to push a pointer to the value you previously pushed.  If it were the other way around, `push rsp` would only push a pointer to itself, which would rarely be useful for anything.